# Update not working-NodeJs and MongoDB using MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was going through the mongodb and nodejs course on [MongoDBUniversity](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2013_August/about) and one of the task involves finding the documents which has the highest recorded temperature for any state and then add a field "month_high" to it.I am able to find the documents for the state with the highest temperature but am unable to update it. The code is as below.

Can someone tell me what might I be doing wrong?

```
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course',function(err,db){
var cursor=db.collection("weather").find();
cursor.sort({"State":1,"Temperature":-1});
var oldState,newState;  
cursor.each(function(err,doc){
    if(err)throw err;
    if(doc==null){
         return db.close();
    }
    newState=doc.State;
    if(newState!=oldState){
        var operator={'$set':{"month_high":true}};
            var query={"_id":doc._id};
            console.log(doc._id+" has temp "+doc.Temperature+" "+doc.State);
            db.collection("weather").update(doc,operator,function(err,updated){
                    console.log("hi");//---->Never Logs
                    if(err)throw err;
                   //   console.log(JSON.stringify(updated));

               })

    }   
    oldState=newState;

});





    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but given the syntax reported on the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html) you might have to specify the options parameter even if not using it:

```
db.collection("weather").update(doc,operator, options, function(err,updated)
```

Also, the connection  might get closed before the callbacks are called. Does it change anything if you remove the `db.close()` call?

Comment: well according to the docs options is optional . I still tried it though as you said but it is still the same.Neither is any error thrown

Comment: Is optional unless you want to provide a callback (again, according to the syntax in the docs, but I think I saw it used the way you did). Does it change anything if you remove the `db.close()` call?

Comment: the {db.close()} call is in the if loop...so i guess that should not matter

Comment: It could because the callbacks are executed asynchronously, while the if statement is synchronous (executed as soon as the cursor is exhausted)

Comment: Yes you were right, it worked... I guess I will have to figure out how to close the db now...If you can edit your answer I can mark it as accepted !:-)

Answer (score 0):

Collection name is 'data'. In this homework 'weather' is database name.

See
https://education.mongodb.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2013_October/courseware/CRUD/Homework_2.2/

```
> use weather
switched to db weather
> db.data.findOne()
```